# React rendering before async function finishes running

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

The program below reads data from a Firebase db and then stores it via setState to a variable. On the first render, no {problem} is undefined and so it cannot be used in the code. This means that React will just render a page with the hardcoded text. As soon as setState is run, the components re-render and the program displays the data. The only problem I have is that when I pass the {problem} variable to a child component, it returns the following error (error occurs on last line in AdditionalInfo.jsx shown).

AdditionalInfo.jsx:45 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Why does the program only return an error for the child component and how can I fix this?

**Problem.jsx**

```
const [problem, setProblem] = useState({});


    useEffect(() => {
        const getProblem = async () => {
            const problemsRef = collection(db, "problems");
            const q = query(problemsRef, where("problemNumber", "==", parseInt(params.id)));
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
            setProblem({...querySnapshot.docs[0].data()});
        }
        getProblem();
    }, [params.id]);
.
.
.

   return (
        <Split
        gutterSize={10}
        gutterAlign="center"
        cursor="col-resize"
        snapOffset={75}
        className='split'
        minSize={0}>
            <div className="bg-gray-100 min-h-screen max-h-screen overflow-y-auto"> {/* min-h-screen causes there to be a small scroll because of the navbar. To fix this use someting like min-h-screen minus height of navbar */}
                <div className='mx-2 my-2 text-1xl font-medium'>
                    {problem.problemNumber}. {problem.problemTitle}
                </div>
                <div className='mx-2 my-2 text-1xl font-normal text-green-600'>
                    {problem.problemType}
                </div>
                <Divider variant="middle" />
                <div className='mx-2 my-2 text-1xl text-base'>
                    {problem.problemQuestion}
                </div>

                <div>
                    {mapToArray(problem.companies).map(([key, value]) => {
                        return <CompanyTag key={key} companyName={value} companyId={key} />
                    }
                    )}
                </div>
                <AdditionalInfo problem={problem}/>
            </div>
                
            <div className="bg-gray-100">
                <div className='mx-7'>
                    <video width="100%" height="100%px" controls>
                        <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>

        </Split>
    )
```

**AdditionalInfo.jsx**

```
const AdditionalInfo = ({ problem }) => {

  return (
    <div>
        {problem.questionTips.map((tip) => {
            return <Tip key={tip.number} number={tip.number} description={tip.description} />
        })} // Code causes an error here
.
.
.
```

Comment: "it returns an error" Please edit the question to show the exact error message and on what line that happens.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen just edited the post

Comment: @EliasFiz lets continue discussion in comments below my answer, if you still have any issues - lets make them clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer as an answer.

Error is due you initially set `const [problem, setProblem] = useState({});` so on first render your problem is just an empty object. In the child component where you passed your `problem` you are trying to use problem.questionTips.map() fn in jsx and due to on first render problem.questionTips is undefined - trying to access .map on undefined gives you your error.

You should use `?` operator to solve this issue.

```
{problem.questionTips?.map((tip) => {
  return <Tip key={tip.number} number={tip.number} description={tip.description} />
})}
```

Answering on additional question in the comment: "Is there a way to full wait until all the data is read from firebase before rendering?"

Yes, there is a way, just use

```
{problem?.questionTips && <AdditionalInfo problem={problem}/>}
```

That will not render your AdditionalInfo component until `problem` with `questionTips` is loaded

Comment: Can you change your `setProblem({...querySnapshot.docs[0].data()});` to `const res = {...querySnapshot.docs[0].data()}; console.log(res); setProblem(res);` just to ensure you really got any data there.

Comment: Just saw an error in the Firebase data formatting that was causing an error with fetching the data. Thanks a lot for your answer as it helped resolve the no data error.